# Xamarin Templates -IOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am currently learning  app-building basics with Xamarin. My question is what is the difference between "Blank-App (iPhone)" and "Master-Detail App (iPhone)".

Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

These are two different templates for you to choose.

**Blank-App (iPhone)** means you just create an empty project without storyboard, RootViewController or other extensions. You can customize it whatever you want.  If you are new to Xamarin.iOS and unsure about what template to use, try to use Single View Application.

**Master-Detail App (iPhone)** means when you choose this template. System will automatically create a `UISplitViewController` with a default `Detail` and `Master` for you. So there's no need to configure the rootView. It's a type of showing the ViewController.

You can try to create these two template projects then run to see the difference between them.